# forEach looping only loop data twice instead the length of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 array look like this, and im trying to update the array
I'm using findIndex() to check the id from both array

```
bin_tierings = [          
    {
        "id": 185,
        "target_amount": "73.000",
        "reward_amount": "88.000"
    },  
    {
        "id": 189,
        "target_amount": "74.000",
        "reward_amount": "99.000"
    },  
    {
        "id": 190,
        "target_amount": "75.000",
        "reward_amount": "111.000"
    },  
    {
        "id": 191,
        "target_amount": "76.000",
        "reward_amount": "122.000"
    }
]
```

```
data_tierings = [  
    {
        "id": 185,
        "target_amount": "80.000",
        "reward_amount": "88.000"
    },  
    {
        "id": 189,
        "target_amount": "81.000",
        "reward_amount": "99.000"
    },  
    {
        "id": 190,
        "target_amount": "82.000",
        "reward_amount": "111.000"
    },  
    {
        "id": 191,
        "target_amount": "83.000",
        "reward_amount": "122.000"
    }
]
```

```
if (data_tierings) {
      data_tierings.forEach((dt) => {
        let idxMissionTier = -1; // reset
        if (bin_tierings && bin_tierings.length) {
          idxMissionTier = bin_tierings.findIndex((bin) => bin.id === dt.id);
        }

        payload.tierings.push({
          id: idxMissionTier !== -1 ? bin_tierings[idxMissionTier].id : 0,
          delete: 0,
          target_amount: dt.target_amount,
          reward_amount: dt.reward_amount
        });
        if (idxMissionTier !== -1) {
          bin_tierings.splice(idxMissionTier, 1);
        }
      });
    }
    if (bin_tierings) {
      bin_tierings.forEach((dt) => {
        payload.tierings.push({
          id: dt.id,
          delete: 1,
          target_amount: dt.target_amount,
          reward_amount: dt.reward_amount
        });
      });
    }
```

When i run the code the payload i get look like this :

```
[
  {
    "id": 185,
    "delete": 0,
    "target_amount": 80,
    "reward_amount": "88.000"
  },
  {
    "id": 190,
    "delete": 0,
    "target_amount": 82,
    "reward_amount": "111.000"
  },
  {
    "id": 189,
    "delete": 1,
    "target_amount": 81,
    "reward_amount": "99.000"
  },
  {
    "id": 191,
    "delete": 1,
    "target_amount": 83,
    "reward_amount": "122.000"
  }
]
```

when I try to run this code, I get `delete = 1` on payload array, it should be all `0` because all the `id` should match between `bin_tierings and data_tierings`
`delete` key on on last two array should be `0` because the index should match, but when i console in looping `forEach`, the loop only run twice, instead 4 according to the length of the data

can anyone help me with my code, any help is appreciated

Comment: When I run your code, I get the expected result, with delete=0 for all elements. Maybe it would be best to create a codesandbox so I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SteffenFrank thankyou for coming in, but I'm afraid it's hard to create the sandbox, but i can elaborate, as you can see the payload `id` is not consecutive, I think after the first loop the data went to `if(bin_tierings)` so the array[1] got the delete=1